# Can't parse data from InputBox as integer (Visual Basic for Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a value that user inputs manually as an integer and I have to take into account the fact that user might not enter an integer. That's why I'm trying to catch a type mismatch error. However, when I enter an integer value I still get type mismatch error.

This is the piece of code that makes this error.

```
Dim number As Integer
On Error GoTo error
    number = InputBox("Enter an integer:")
error:
    MsgBox ("Input error. Make sure you enter an integer value.")
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: please add `Exit sub` before `error:`

Comment: You don't have any mechanism there to skip the error message so it will always appear.

Comment: One more suggestion- try to avoid reserved words or reserved-like words when using your own names. Therefore instead of `error` label you could use quite common `ErrorHandler`

Comment: @KazimierzJawor I know how error handling works. The point I am making (as you also mentioned) is that there is nothing in the code posted to ever skip the `Msgbox` line. (note: simply adding `Exit Sub` would seem to make the code a little pointless)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Application.InputBox Method` allows you to specify what the Type of data returned.

[MSDN Application.InputBox Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx)

[image]

```
Sub Example1()
    Dim number As Integer
    number = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter an integer:", Type:=1)

End Sub
```

Because `Application.InputBox` with the Type 1 parameter will return 0 if the user cancels, I would prefer to use a standard `InputBox`.  The way to use it is to have a separate variable capture the value and test that the return value meets your criteria.  In this way, you can avoid any errors.

```
Sub Example2()
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim result As String
    result = InputBox("Enter an integer:")
    If result = "" Then
        MsgBox "Good Bye", vbInformation, "Action Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf IsNumeric(result) Then
        If CDbl(result) > CInt(result) Then
            MsgBox "You entered a Decimal" & vbCrLf & "Try Again", vbInformation, "Intergers Only"
        Else
           number = result
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Intergers Only" & vbCrLf & "Try Again", vbInformation, "Intergers Only"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
Dim number                As Integer
On Error Resume Next
number = InputBox("Enter an integer:")
If Err.number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Input error. Make sure you enter an integer value.")
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Note though that this will accept non-integer number entries; it's not clear if that's a concern.

Comment: Thanks. This worked though I had to modify it so that it stores only integer values.